# Running C++ program from ruby

Tags: c++, ruby-on-rails, ruby, shell

How can you run a C++ program from a Ruby script?

Suppose that the Ruby script generates a file, called "hello.txt" and I want to run a C++ program to take the hello.txt file, work with it and write another file, called "result.txt" and the Ruby script continues to read the result.txt file.

For example, in the Linux shell I wrote `g++ hello.c -c hello -o hello` to receive the "result.txt" file.

Is there is a way that I can run the shell code from a Ruby program?

Comment: Your example command is compiling the C++ file (please use .cpp as an extension next time for sanity) and not running it, that would be achieved afterwards with `$ ./hello [ARGS]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [system](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-system) :

```
system("./hello file.txt")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `system` like other people said, however you should also check the exit value to verify the success or failure.

```
r = system("g++ hello.c -c hello -o hello") #=> r = true if success, nil if failed
```

Answer (score 1):

I find that [backticks](http://rubyquicktips.com/post/5862861056/execute-shell-commands) are more succinct than `system`.

You can trigger the C++ program by shelling out as follows:

```
`./hello file.txt`
```

Can you clarify whether you need to read results.txt from the current directory?

If so, you could use something like `contents = IO::readlines './results.txt'`

Comment: [Backticks](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-60) behave differently than [`system`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-system); The first return the result of the STDOUT from the child app, whereas `system` returns the status of the called code. They're not interchangeable because they behave differently.

Comment: I agree but he didn't say that he was examining the response code. I suggested backticks because he could have the results.txt explicitly returned to stdout from C++ program instead of writing to a file (arguably more UNIX-like), which would work nicely here (avoiding touching the disk and then reading again after). No harm in considering a different approach :-)

Comment: I should have probably elaborated slightly more in hindsight!

Comment: Then using [`Open3.capture2`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-capture2) or [`Open3.popen2`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-popen2) would make more sense. The `3` varients of those two methods are useful if capturing STDERR could be an issue.

Comment: Thanks for sharing those! I learned something new, will keep these in mind next time I am shelling out (though usually I just produce a native extension module for this sort of task since I am used to the boilerplate by now.)